# Conversion between Rectangular and Polar Coordinates with Matlab

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates, radians, cartesian-coordinates

```
[X,Y] = pol2cart(-radtodeg(acos(RPF)),RCurrent);
```

This is where my code goes wrong. I'm writing a code to find out the sending end parameters of a transmission line with given Receiving end current (RCurrent -> 2000) and power factor (RPF -> 0.8). Hand Calculations give me a value of 1600 - 1200j. But Matlab calculations give me a different value. **In short I need to convert 2000 at -36.86 degrees to rectangular form.** Can you guys help me :) ?

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted to close the question.

Comment: It says I should wait for 2 days to mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh never mind. The radtodeg function is making the answer incorrect. There was a mis understanding about the syntax of the conversion :)